# sklearn binary classifier for dataset with datetime, categorical values without preprocessing?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I need to predict if signup-driver will actually start driving using some basic classifier.

```
city_name   signup_os   signup_channel  signup_date bgc_date    first_completed_date    did_drive
Strark      ios web     Paid             1/2/16     NaN         NaN                     no

Strark      windows     Paid             1/21/16    NaN         NaN                     no
```

the dataset has some date columns, what classifier from sklearn to use to train basic classifier?

it fails with datetime values. All the features are categorical or date values

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
  


X = refined_df[['city_name','signup_os','signup_channel','signup_date','bgc_date']]

y = refined_df['did_drive']




from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y , test_size=0.25, random_state=0)

models = {}

# Logistic Regression
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
models['Logistic Regression'] = LogisticRegression()

# Support Vector Machines
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
models['Support Vector Machines'] = LinearSVC()

# Decision Trees
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
models['Decision Trees'] = DecisionTreeClassifier()

# Random Forest
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
models['Random Forest'] = RandomForestClassifier()

# Naive Bayes
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
models['Naive Bayes'] = GaussianNB()

# K-Nearest Neighbors
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
models['K-Nearest Neighbor'] = KNeighborsClassifier()



from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score

accuracy, precision, recall = {}, {}, {}

for key in models.keys():
    
    # Fit the classifier
    models[key].fit(X_train, y_train)
    
    # Make predictions
    predictions = models[key].predict(X_test)
    
    # Calculate metrics
    accuracy[key] = accuracy_score(predictions, y_test)
    precision[key] = precision_score(predictions, y_test)
    recall[key] = recall_score(predictions, y_test)
```

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Berton'. it cant convert city name to float. how to do it?

is there decision tree that accept datetime values without any additional conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply one-hot encoding to convert categorical features into numerical ones. Scikit-learn provides the OneHotEncoder

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
X_categorical = encoder.fit_transform(X[['city_name', 'signup_os', 'signup_channel']])
```

Regarding the date conversion, you can extract some information from the actual date or you can try a unix timestamp conversion.

```
X['signup_year'] = X['signup_date'].dt.year
X['signup_month'] = X['signup_date'].dt.month
```

Finally, rebuild the final input and split it.

```
X = np.concatenate((X_categorical, X[['signup_year', 'signup_month']]), axis=1)
```